# Opencart module for all the pages

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

I am creating a banner module in opencart and I want to assign this to all layouts so that it will show on all the pages but opencart there is no option for select multi layout on one click.
How can I assign module to all the layout in one place any help should be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: In opencart 2.0, there is no way to select multi-select layout. You have to do custom work on the your custom banner module.  You can give your own configuration i.e. **Assign layout option** in that module.

Comment: Download this http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=16689 free module. You may get an idea from it.

Comment: @VedPandya : extension, you have shared on is not compatible with opencart 2.0 or above.

Comment: Yes i know it, but you can get an idea from it. Something is better than nothing. ;)

Comment: Just replace `$this->data` with `$data` and upload the XML. It might work if you haven't modified core files.

Answer (score 0):

This module is what you need is:

[Layout Show All Pages - show same module on all pages 2.X](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=28519&sort=date_added)